# On hover and on click function / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I posted a question few hours back but my example was not perfect to understand.

So here it goes.

I have two big boxes. On hover each of the big red box, the small black box should change it's bg color.When you click on each big box then the small box color should change as well.On mouse enter and out it's working fine. But onclick it's not working. I tried with bind/unbind but didn't work.

Jquery:

```
$('.libg').click(function () {
    $('.imagebg').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.imagebg').addClass('active');
}).hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('.imagebg').addClass('active');
},
function () {
    $(this).find('.imagebg').removeClass('active');
});
```

Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/kdZ8J/2/

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Negative voting!!!..didn't expect that though.

Comment: "When you click on each small box then the box color should change as well." ==> Which box color should change? the big one or the small one?

Comment: @NKD...The small one.

Answer (score 0):

I would check each box separately. So I'm going to modify your html code a bit along with some jquery code. http://jsfiddle.net/kdZ8J/15/

Html code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="libg1" id="1">
    <div class="imagebg1" id="1a"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="libg2" id="2">
    <div class="imagebg2" id="2a"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Handle click events:

```
$('#1').click(function () {
   //add the click and set active class
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
   $('#1a').addClass('active');
   //remove the click and active class
   $('#2').data('clicked', false);
   $('#2a').removeClass('active');
})
$('#2').click(function () {
   //add the click and set active class
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
   $('#2a').addClass('active');
   //remove the click and active class
   $('#1').data('clicked', false);
   $('#1a').removeClass('active');
})
```

First Rectugular Hovering code:

```
$('.libg1').hover(function () {
  if($(this).data('clicked')) {
    //check if active class exists
    if($('.active').size()){
      $('#1a').removeClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $('#1a').addClass('active');
    }
  }
  else{
    $('#1a').addClass('active');
  }
},function () {
    if($(this).data('clicked')) {
      $('#1a').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $('#1a').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Second Rectangular Hoving code:

```
$('.libg2').hover(function () {
   if($(this).data('clicked')) {
     //check if active class exists
     if($('.active').size()){
       $('#2a').removeClass('active');
     }
     else{
       $('#2a').addClass('active');
     }
   }
   else{
     $('#2a').addClass('active');
   }
},function () {
   if($(this).data('clicked')) {
     $('#2a').addClass('active');
   }
   else{
     $('#2a').removeClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question. Onclick each big box the small box color should change as well.

Comment: Okay your code is doing a circluar add/remove class. Your click is actually working but since you are binding that with the hover, it reverses it back.

Comment: the solution is to check whether the bigger box "was clicked". So in your click() function you could check if the bigger box has been clicked before with something like this  $(this).data('clicked', true); And then in your hover() function add an if statement to perform the add/remove class base on whether it has been clicked before.

Comment: Okay - i updated my answer with a sample code on how to check if it was clicked.  you have to give me more info on the requirments so I can help you.

Comment: Close...Onething that is when you click a box then it needs to remove class active from all boxes and then put the class 'active' for the clicked box.Let me try.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... :(

Comment: I have to leave for an appointment. Give it try and if you still need help, give me some clarification and I'll check back with you tomorrow. Good Luck!

Comment: I think it's not possible what I am going to achieve..I have to find some other way.

Comment: hi - i'm just checking back. Sorry for leaving in a rush yesterday. Let me know if I can help with anything.

Comment: Okay so I think I know what you are trying to do. For future reference, here is how I would word your requirments: 1. Create two RED rectangular boxes (one on the right and one on the left). 2. Inside each RED rectangular you just created, create a small BLACK square box on the top left corner. 3. When hover the mouse over each RED rectangular, the BLACK square box inside the rectangular should change to GREY. 4. If the BLACK square box is clicked/selected, its color changes to GREY and the other square box becomes unclicked/unselected/BLACK.

Comment: So here is the code :) http://jsfiddle.net/kdZ8J/15/ I'll update my answer in a bit

Comment: I have created a new fiddle as well as a question. http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/5/ Please look at this. Everything is working great just one small issue. When you click red box the black box changes but when you click second time the grey box is not changing to black box. So on click the red box it should toggle class.

Comment: this is what I was trying to do...Solved!! http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/17/ Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting lines of code:

```
$('.imagebg').removeClass('active');
$(this).find('.imagebg').addClass('active');
```

The first line will remove the class, and the second will add the class right back to the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdZ8J/4/

```
$('.libg').click(function () {
    var current = $(this).find('.imagebg');
    var all = $('.imagebg');
    var index = all.index(current);

    $('.imagebg').each(function(i) {
        if(i != index) {
            $(all[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    if(current.hasClass('active')) {
        current.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        current.addClass('active');
    }
}).hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('.imagebg').addClass('active');
},
function () {
    $(this).find('.imagebg').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Yes because only one small box can have class active one at a time.

Comment: Do you see all the information you have left out of the question? It is impossible for us to help you with so much missing information.